# Как сделать правильно запрос к таблице?

Tags: mysql, sql

Как сделать запрос так что бы в результате мне вышла таблица где product_id соответствовал бы одновременно 2 условиям например attribute_id = 12 и attribute_id = 17.

На выходе должна бы получиться таблица с 2 строчками: 1,2;

```
SELECT pa.product_id FROM product_attribute pa WHERE pa.attribute_id IN (12) AND pa.attribute_id IN (17)
```

так конечно же работать не будет, но хоть как то поможет понять суть задачи.

Разве что делать SELECT -> SELECT

[image: Сама таблица]

Comment: `select product_id from product_attribute group by product_id having max(attribute_id = 12) and max(attribute_id = 17)`

Comment: @PetSerAl А почему не в форме ответа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT product_id 
FROM product_attribute 
WHERE attribute_id IN (12, 17)
GROUP BY product_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT attribute_id) = 2
```

> можете расписать схему работы ?

Выделяем (WHERE) записи с заданными значениями attribute_id. Считаем, сколько разных (DISTNCT) attribute_id выделено для каждого product_id (GROUP BY). Оставляем только те product_id (HAVING), для которых посчитанное количество равно количеству разных attribute_id в списке (т.е. для которых присутствует хотя бы по одному разу каждый заданный attribute_id).

Comment: можете расписать схему работы ?
Вроде все ясно - но все же )

Comment: @MaksDevda Добавил описание. Подробнее - ищите по словам "реляционное деление".

Comment: лаконичное решение, а то я пошел путем JOIN иду переделывать ) Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    pa.product_id
FROM
    product_attribute pa
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        product_id
        ,COUNT(*) Num
    FROM
        product_attribute
    GROUP BY
        product_id
) T ON T.product_id = pa.product_id
WHERE
    attribute_id IN (12, 17)
GROUP BY
    pa.product_id
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = MAX(T.Num)
```

Comment: Первый не подойдет так как мне нужно что бы идентификатор соответствовал и 12 и 11 одновременно, 
второй же запрос вернет 0, так как идет запросто построчно и не одно поле не будет равно и 12 и 17  одновременно

Comment: Не верно понял вопрос, изменил ответ

Comment: к сожалению не работает (